# Window decoration which respects titlebar colour AND supports Attach as Tab

Tags: kubuntu, usability

It seems that some KDE features, such as Attach as Tab, are [windows decoration dependent](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=123945). Specifically, the otherwise excellent Plastik windows decoration does not support Attach as Tab.

The default windows decoration, Oxygen, does support Attach as Tab however the titlebar colour is a dull grey and that makes it [difficult to determine which window is the active window](https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=24126&action=view) when many windows are open. Oxygen [ignores the configured titlebar colour](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152030).

Which available KDE themes support *both* titlebar colour *and* Attach as Tab? **Is there any way to check these features before downloading and installing each theme individually?**